# Adding custom Log Level in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

How to add custom log level in `Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE`., like

`LOGGER.audit("my message");`

and then use `ThresholdFilter` in `logback.xml` to able to write them in separate log file

`<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>AUDIT</level>
</filter>`

My application is using `org.slf4j.Logger`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to define a custom log level in slf4j. What you could do though is make the audit messages easily distinguishable (let's say by prefixing each message with "AUDIT") and create a custom filter like described here: http://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/filters/SampleFilter.html